# Exception when trying to compile project inside Android studio

Tags: android, logcat

I have the following error when I try to compile my project; any body knows what I can do with this error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent, PID: 15284
>                                                                                            java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface;
>   in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent-sYwk5YXA0Ap8nyn-79YvKg==/base.apk)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:753)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:621)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:631)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.SingleFragmentActivity.onCreate(SingleFragmentActivity.java:21)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Here is the part it says it is failing in the log

```
         public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity

                   {
                        protected abstract Fragment createFragment();//abstract method
                          @Override
                                 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                        ***setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);***
                                   FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                 Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                                   if (fragment == null) {
                               fragment = createFragment();
                                 fm.beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
                                  .commit();
                                                        }
                                  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to read and understand what Android Studio is telling you. In this case it tells you quite plainly that there is no such method as `getFont()` in the current context. You probably wanted/should've used `ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.your_font);` but there is no way to know because you didn't post a sample of your code. Please review Stack Overflow's posting guidelines. This will save everyone a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. It is likely that at this point, due to the speculative nature of the response, it would be more appropriate as a comment (once you have 50 rep), but the remarks here are correct that OP should read error, what you state is the likely resolution, and that a sample is missing but would have been helpful.

Comment: I can't comment yet. If I could, I would have. Thanks! :)